# How to access Function Key's in Azure Function using C#?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I can't access the Function Key's of my Azure Function from C# code.

I've been searching the web for a solution, but I haven't found anything useful.

Normally I would use a configuration file in my project.
Do I somehow have to add the keys in my project before I can access them in runtime?

Comment: How do you provide them to authorize your function?

Answer (score 0):

Given you've provided nothing concrete re: the context for where you're executing this from, all I can do is give you a basic boilerplate program that helps you along.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureManagement
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetWebSites().Wait();
        }

        static async Task GetWebSites()
        {
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
            var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();

            // App Services
            var webSitesEnumerator = subscription.GetWebSitesAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();

            try
            {
                while (await webSitesEnumerator.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var webSite = webSitesEnumerator.Current;
                    var hostKeys = await webSite.GetHostKeysAsync();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                await webSitesEnumerator.DisposeAsync();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see by the `using` statements that you'll need a few nuget packages installed ...

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
```

... and you'll also need to make sure the relevant auth is setup in order to make the call.

That gives me both the master and the function key(s) ...

[image: Result]